# ¿Como adiconar una etiqueta span a una palabra en toda la web?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-webflow

tengo un problema con la implementación del Translate de Google, me esta traduciendo una palabra en especifico que no deseo sea traducida ya que representa el slogan, he intentado agregarle por javascript el atributo **translate="no"** pero no he conseguido encontrar como adicionar esta excepción..

Estos son los codigos que tengo para adicionar a la etiqueta title el atributo
**translate="no"**

```
(function() {
    const title = document.querySelector("title");
    title.setAttribute("translate", "no");   
  })();
```

La solución esta implementada en WebFlow, la documentación que use para implementarla esta en esta url
https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/gtranslate-2

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que quieres lograr... La función debe buscar todos los elementos que tengan el atributo `tilte` y agregarles el atributo `translate="no"`?

Comment: Debo buscar la palabra BUILT en todo la web. Esta función me permitio adicionar el atributo translate="no" en el title del head, pero necesito tambien adicionar este atributo, ya sea en un span donde encuentre la palabra que Necesito que no sea traducida.

Comment: Asumo que el cambio debe ser permanente. Te sugiero usar las opciones de búsqueda en tu editor de código para buscar la palabra en todo el proyecto y agregar el `span` de forma masiva **desde el código** en lugar de hacerlo de forma dinámica con `JS`.